# SQL Server 2019 Express limited to 1 socket/4 cores per instance. Can different instances then use different sockets?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

We have a SQL Express 2019 server with 3 instances.
The VM has 2 sockets each with 2 cores. The SQL Express licensing specifies that a SQL Express **instance** can use the lessor of 1 socket or 4 cores. So far so good.
Each instance however is picking socket 0 to use, so all 3 instances are sharing 2 cores while the 2 cores on socket 1 are at idle. Is there a way to assign specific instances to specific sockets? The wording of the license seems to indicate that 3 instances on the same machine could use a total of 12 cores, up to 1 socketx4 cores per instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can install as many instances as you want, and use an [affinity mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/affinity-mask-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) to specify which instances use which cores.  I believe this all works on Express.

Comment: It does work with Express, but requires a restart to kick in.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting the answer, but in SSMS->instance properties->Processors you can choose which core, but it seems only one of the two sockets are available

e.g.
https://imgur.com/a/yWLn7pf